# regular expressions with word boundaries fail in .NET Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a problem with .NET regular expressions in C#. We are trying to match special tokens in a text surrounded by the paragraph sign `§`. For completeness those the corresponding regular expressions are surrounded by word boundaries `\b`. The problem is that the regular expression surrounded by `\b` does not match words:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = "I would like to replace this §pattern§ with something interesting";
        string requiredResult = "I would like to replace this serious text with something interesting";

        Regex regSuccess = new Regex("§pattern§");
        Regex regFail = new Regex(@"\b§pattern§\b");

        var dataSuccess = regSuccess.Replace(data, "serious text");
        var dataFail = regFail.Replace(data, "serious text");

        Console.WriteLine("regSuccess match: {0}", dataSuccess == requiredResult);
        Console.WriteLine("regFail match: {0}", dataFail == requiredResult);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue");
        var line = Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As you can see, `dataFail == requiredResult` returns `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
Regex regFail = new Regex(@"\b§pattern§\b");
```

with

```
Regex regFail = new Regex(@"§\bpattern\b§");
```

`§` is a non-word character, thus, `\b` prevents `pattern` from being matched. Perhaps, you do not even need the `\b` here since the `pattern` is already inside the non-word characters?

```
Regex regFail = new Regex(@"§pattern§");
```

Comment: You're right, the word boundaries are entirely superfluous.  They're for times when you don't know (or care) what the other character will be, just that it can't be a word character.